# Eclipse from multiple computers/users at same time?

Tags: java, eclipse, networking, collaboration

I want to setup eclipse on a network drive and have it so me and my friend can code at the same time on the same project and the code update automatically on both computers.

Comment: Sounds like you need some kind of collaboration feature. I'm sure there is a project out there for this, but I'm not aware of it. However, I have had no trouble setting up eclipse projects on a network drive for me to access on different workstations.

Comment: Eclipse itself is not a multi-user software as I know, why don't you use version control system like SVN?

Comment: I don't know if Eclipse Orion does collaboration? http://www.eclipse.org/orion/

Answer (score 5):

The standard way to do something like this is by using [version control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control). It will require a certain amount of discipline, but will bring many benefits.

You certainly don't want to simultaneously work on the same copy of the code. Just imagine your friend starting to make changes to an important class; all of a sudden you can't do any work since the project won't build or won't run until your friend is finished.

Instead, you'd each work on your own copy of the project, and periodically *commit* stable versions of the code into the shared repository for your collaborators to see.

Comment: +1. Use version control and set up Hudson/Jenkins or whatever for continouus integration if you are ambitious...

Answer (score 0):

I am doing the same thing as you. My friend and I are working on the same project together. We use a dropbox shared folder to share codes, only you can only edit one at a time. It works for us becuase we are coding unrelated parts of the project.